# How to create sequence using checkbox winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, sequence

Three `Checkbox` in Winform if I checked the *third* checkbox its returned as `3` if I checked the *second* checkbox returned as `2` if the *first* checkbox is unchecked returned as 0 at last get sequence `[3,2,0]` Eg if a second checked box is unchecked first checkbox is checked it returned as a sequence `[3,0,1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's *organize* the checkboxes into a collection, say, an array, `Tuple<CheckBox, int>[]`:

```
  // Check box and its corresponding value
  private Tuple<CheckBox, int>[] map => new Tuple<CheckBox, int>[] {
    Tuple.Create(checkBox1, 3),
    Tuple.Create(checkBox2, 2),
    Tuple.Create(checkBox3, 1), 
  };

  // Now we can query the collection with a help of Linq
  private int[] mapBoxes() => map
    .Select(pair => pair.Item1.Checked ? pair.Item2 : 0)
    .ToArray();

  ...

  int[] values = mapBoxes();
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using `Tuple<Checkbox, int>[]` over `Dictionary<Checkbox, int>`?

Comment: @TvanB: `Dictionary` is not guaranteed to *be sorted*, so we can get `[1, 3, 0]` instead of `[3, 0, 1]`; the right values in wrong order

Comment: @Harish: I see, sorry, let's turn `map` into a readonly property with `=>` instead of `=`

Comment: @Harish: I've done it: `private Tuple<CheckBox, int>[] map => new Tuple<CheckBox, int>[] {`, please, note, `=>` instead of `=`

Comment: To link a value to a checkBox (or to every control), you can use its `Tag` property, so you don't need a dictionary, you can just use the built in way

Comment: @Gian Paolo: yes, there's a possibility, but using `Tag` makes the code, IMHO, less readable: if we want to, say, add `checkBox4` with value `10`, and change `checkBox2` value into `5` we can easily find out where to do it; in case of `Tag` it can be not that clear

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I would setup the tag values in a method, not with designer, so you have a single point in code where these values are set. It's just that I would prefer to avoid to create a "complex" (not so complex, actually...) structure when the framework already offers a way to link a control to some value

Comment: @DmitryBychenko `OrderedDictionary` is guaranteed to be insertion order.

Comment: @TvanB: `OrderedDictionary` is a solution, but *in general case* (what if we want to have, say, `[3, 1, 2]` order?) we have to *implement custom comparer*, when in case of array we have the right order for *free*

Comment: @DmitryBychenko `OrderedDictionary` is insertion order, so would not differ from an array.

Answer (score 1):

So you want the third checkbox to be placed first in your array and toggle between 3 and 0, second checkbox is second in array toggling between 2 and 0 and first checkbox is third in array and toggles between 1 and 0:

```
int[] cb = new int[]{
  thirdCheckbox.Checked?3:0,
  secondCheckbox.Checked?2:0,
  firstCheckbox.Checked?1:0
};
```